# a couple of simple questions about basic pointer use in c++ and the c++ memory model

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I've been studying along with the Stanford courses on iTunes U and have hit pointers in C++. I think I understand how pointers work, but I just want to check how to do some simple stuff. Let's say I want to create a dynamic array:

```
    double *array;
```

At this point there's a variable called "array" in the stack and nothing in the heap. First question - what's stored in "array" at this point? A pointer to some nonsense piece of memory?

I then allocate memory using "new":

```
    array = new double[10];
```

Second question - at this point, what's stored in "array"? A pointer to some contiguous piece of memory big enough to hold ten doubles? (Sorry for the simple questions, but I really want to make sure I understand)

I assign the double 2.0 to each element in the array:

```
    for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) array[i]=2.0;
```

Third question - is this different from using the dereference operator to assign? (i.e., `*array[i]=2.0`). I then pass the array to some other function:

```
    myFunc(double array[]){
        for(int i=1; i<array.length(); i++){
            array[i]=array[i]*array[i-1];
        }
    }
```

Fourth question - on the pass to myFunc, since array is an array of pointers to doubles, and not an array of doubles, it passes by reference without "&", right? That means the operations in my loop are affecting the actual data stored in "array". What if I wanted to pass by value, so that I wouldn't be touching the data in "array"? Would I use

```
    myFunc(double *array[]){...}?
```

Last question - what if I wanted to manipulate the memory addresses for the contents of "array" for some reason? Could i use

```
    someVar = &array[5];
```

to assign the the hex address of array[5] to someVar?

I've read the section on pointers in the reader and watched the Binky video a dozen times and it still doesn't make sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks a lot to everyone who answered so far. If you wouldn't mind I just have one more question. In the declaration `double *array;`, "array" is declared as a pointer to a double, but once I use "new" to assign it, "array" ceases being a pointer to a double, and becomes an array of doubles, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `array` contains junk data - whatever was in that memory location before `array` existed is still there. If you try to play with it you're going to shoot yourself in the foot, which is why you need to assign it to a valid memory location, (hence the ensuing call to `new[]`).
2. Yes, `array` now contains a pointer (memory address) to some contiguous piece of memory big enough to hold ten doubles.
3. `*array[i]=2.0` won't actually compile. array[i] results in a `double`, and you can't use the dereference operator on a double.
4. What you're passing is that address to the first element in the array. So you are passing the pointer by value, and the array by reference (as the pointer is a reference to the array.) To pass the array itself by value you'd have to have one parameter for each entry. You could also copy the array and send in the copy, but the copy itself would be passed by reference, too.
5. `double* someVar = &array[5];` will return to you a pointer to the 6<sup>th</sup> element of the array. `array[5]` gives you the double, and taking the address of it (with `&`) will give you the memory address (pointer) of that double.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yep, that's what's happening
2. Most definitely. More specifically, a pointer to the *beginning* of a contiguous piece of memory.
3. Not in this case; `*` (for dereference) is a unary operator, and yet you have passed it two arguments. You can be sure it is multiplication that is performed (or an overloaded version of it) - also, what could `array[i](*array[i-1])` mean? you can't dereference something that isn't a pointer (or doesn't have the unary `*` operator overloaded)
4. You're only passing the pointer by value and not the data. If you want to pass the data by value (make it unchanged outside the function), you'd have to copy it first, and pass that (or just use a `vector`)
5. Yes, you're just getting the address of a part of contiguous memory, and you can store the address and modify the dereferenced value elsewhere, the array *will* be modified also.

Also, be weary that when you allocate on the heap, you have to delete the memory afterwards. In this case, you would use `delete[] array;`

Answer (score 1):

After declaration, the `array` variable contains an arbitary value. You're not allowed to do anything with that value. After `new`, it contains a pointer to a contiguous range of memory large enough to hold 10 doubles. `*array[i]=2.0` is an error (that would imply that array is an array of *pointers* to double). Indexing operator `[]` is just a syntactic sugar for `*(array+i)=2.0`.

Forth question: SAY WHAT?? You don't have an array of pointers to doubles anywhere in that code. In functions, `void f(double *x)` and `void f(double x[])` are THE SAME THING: a pointer to double. If you pass to `f` an array, `x` will receive the address of the first element (which is the VALUE of an array).

You can't pass arrays by value. Alternatively, they are always passed by value (as everything else in C), but note that the VALUE of an array is the address of its first element.

Your last question: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but the question clearly shows that you're confused. An address is an address, there's no such thing as "hex address".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I meant "address", but wanted to distinguish between the data stored at that address and the address itself. I'm not trying to achieve anything in particular, I'm trying to figure out what the operators do.